# KMP - Compilation failed: Generation of stubs for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrTypeParameterPublicSymbolImpl is not supported yet

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to build my KMP project for android and IOS target. On android everything works fine, IOS builds however fail for every target giving strange compilation errors:

```
     w: Cannot infer a bundle ID from packages of source files and exported dependencies, use the bundle name instead: shared

e: kotlin.NotImplementedError: Generation of stubs for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrTypeParameterPublicSymbolImpl is not supported yet
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.linkage.partial.MissingDeclarationStubGenerator.getDeclaration(MissingDeclarationStubGenerator.kt:57)
```

Here's my current configuration:

```
kotlin.version=1.9.0
agp.version=7.4.2
compose.version=1.4.3

plugins {
        val kotlinVersion = extra["kotlin.version"] as String
        val agpVersion = extra["agp.version"] as String
        val composeVersion = extra["compose.version"] as String

        kotlin("jvm").version(kotlinVersion)
        kotlin("multiplatform").version(kotlinVersion)
        kotlin("android").version(kotlinVersion)

        id("com.android.application").version(agpVersion)
        id("com.android.library").version(agpVersion)

        id("org.jetbrains.compose").version(composeVersion)
    }
```

Other libraries:

```
 api("moe.tlaster:precompose:1.4.3")
 api("moe.tlaster:precompose-viewmodel:1.4.3") // For ViewModel intergration
```

There's something in conflict between my kotlin version and compose multiplatform version?

Comment: Please create an issue with your reproducer project attached https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: Can you add the other libraries that you're using? It seems that one might be incompatible with that version of Compose/Kotlin

Comment: @cmota the problem seemed to be related to the precompose library version I was using. By updating the version to 1.5.0-beta01 everything turned out fine